# NULL in previously set environment variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a basic Java IDE in Notepad++, which is easy as long as you don't use packages. But if you need to use the `-classpath` parameter, everything gets difficult.

I want to use these codes, I think you can get the idea:

### NPP EXEC code:

```dos
NPP_SAVE
SET_ENV NPP_FULL_CURRENT_PATH=$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
SET_ENV NPP_CURRENT_DIRECTORY=$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
SET_ENV NPP_NAME_PART=$(NAME_PART)
npp_run cmd /k d:\Users\User\Desktop\script.cmd
```

### script.cmd

```dos
SETX CLASSPATH %CD%
set /p deep=Deepness:
:START
if /I %deep% EQU 0 goto END
cd ..
set /a deep=deep-1
goto START
:END
SETX CLASSPATH %CD%
javac -g -cp %CLASSPATH% %NPP_FULL_CURRENT_PATH%
set /p input=Package:
SETX PACKAGE %input%
java -cp %CLASSPATH% %PACKAGE%.%NPP_NAME_PART%
```

### cmd windows

```dos
D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05\konyves>SETX CLASSPATH D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05\konyves

SIKERÜLT: A megadott értéket sikerült menteni.

D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05\konyves>set /p deep=Deepness:
Deepness:1

D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05\konyves>if /I 1 EQU 0 goto END

D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05\konyves>cd ..

D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05>set /a deep=deep-1

D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05>goto START

D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05>if /I 0 EQU 0 goto END

D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05>SETX CLASSPATH D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05

SIKERÜLT: A megadott értéket sikerült menteni.

D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05>javac -g -cp NULL D:\Users\User\Desktop\programozas\java\P05\konyves\KonyvProba.java
```

(SIKERÜLT means SUCCESS, it managed to save the value)

### THE PROBLEM

You can see the problem in the last line of the cmd window. `-cp NULL`
I don't understand why it's NULL, I've set it in the previous line.

Comment: I've set before an "CLASSPATH" environment variable with NPP EXEC, and with the value "NULL". The NPP EXEC's child process couldn't overwrite the existing variable for some reason, and that caused the problem. Now the compiling part works, the running still not

Comment: Well, I really hate Windows now. All I had to do is "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These codes seem to work now, but may be unstable:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CD%
REM Type in the relative path deepness, for
REM example "package xxx.xxx.xxx;" means 3 deepness
REM No package means 0 deepness
set /p deep=Deepness:
set /a DEEP_FINAL=deep
:START
if /I %deep% EQU 0 goto END
cd ..
set /a deep=deep-1
goto START
:END
set CLASSPATH=%CD%
REM Compiling
javac -g -cp %CLASSPATH% %NPP_FULL_CURRENT_PATH%
REM Executing
if /I %DEEP_FINAL% EQU 0 goto NOPATH
REM May include a "cls" here
REM Type in the package name, for example
REM "package java.util;" becomes "java.util"
set /p PACKAGE=Package:
cls
java -cp %CLASSPATH% %PACKAGE%.%NPP_NAME_PART%
goto FINISH
:NOPATH
cls
java -cp %CLASSPATH% %NPP_NAME_PART%
:FINISH
```

## NPPEXEC code:

```
cd d:
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
NPP_SAVE
SET_ENV NPP_FULL_CURRENT_PATH=$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
SET_ENV NPP_CURRENT_DIRECTORY=$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
SET_ENV NPP_NAME_PART=$(NAME_PART)
npp_run cmd /k d:\Users\User\Desktop\script.cmd
```

This may be different for you. For example most users use the c: partition for the source files. Very important: you have to run Notepad++ as administrator! I'll test this from now on, and if it keeps working, I'll post it with more relevant tags, since it would be a Java IDE with Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

`SETX` does **not** set the environment variable in the current `cmd` instance, but for furure `cmd` instances. You need to execute a `set` command to set the value in the current instance.